# How it is better to do shopping cart in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How it is better to count for each line item it's total cost, and then for all count total summary? I have such db: article has table existence where i have prices, but how to display price * quantity? it's better to do in controller? or in model, but when in model, how to do this, note, in db I have only price, and quantity is given in line item:
I want something like this:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    belongs_to :cart
    def total_price
      existence.PRICEM * quantity
    end
end
```

Comment: i ask, that how to access this quantity * price, this price, if it's not stored in lineitem, only id is stored in lineitem i need to go to another model = existence, take from there price (for every it's id in lineitem) and then price*quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This core business functionality should reside in your models.

Your cart could have:

```
class Cart
  def total_price
    line_items.inject(0.0){|sum,line_item| sum + line_item.total_price }
  end
end

class LineItem
  def total_price
    quantity * price
  end
end
```

This way you can still loop over your line-items to show their price, and then your cart as well. As this transfers to an order, you'll want to store those values rather than calculate them.

Comment: i ask, that how to access this quantity * price, this price, if it's not stored in lineitem, only id is stored in lineitem

Comment: i need to go to another model = existence, take from there price (for every it's id in lineitem) and then price*quantity

Comment: existence is table where I store all prices and availability for articles, a write this is question!

Comment: Does a line_item belong to an existence?

Comment: Absolutely This should be there

Comment: I can solve this in such way: `item_price = Existence.find_by_ART_ID(article_id) item_price.PRICEM * quantity` but then how to calculate sum? it's bad idea, so i need something like up^

Comment: all good) i get stupid little bit( in model i have non-my db, so i have to write all tables and prim keys in existence model, and all is good